# Inquiry about some function in Java, Android Home screen

Tags: java, android

I'm amateur "programmer" I'm looking for one function that I would like to do but I can't find my answer anywhere.

Lets get to business..

I need function similar to main screen where you can GRAB and drag app icons and put them in specific place.

and more exactly I will have like 10 empty (slots) and I would like to grab icon from home screen and drag it and put this icon in one of the empty "slots" in MY APP.

And of course you would be able to exchange the position of them like : all slots are taken, but I want to put ex. FB icon instead of Whatsapp icon so I can switch them just like in home screen of every phone.

Hope I did explain it good and somebody can give me aany advice.
Really appreciate it!

Best regards

Archie

Comment: "I would like to grab icon from home screen and drag it and put this icon in one of the empty "slots" in MY APP" -- were you planning on writing your own home screen?

Comment: Start with creating grids , assign some id for each grid that is going to hold icon and store your ids for a grid in some data structure where you map the grid id with icons. You need to determine in which grid the drag started and where it is released so that you can swap the icons association in the grid id in your datastructure holding the link and redraw the screen.